# Node.js, Vue.js and Passport.js. .isAuthenticated() always returns false? Axios headers possibly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, vue.js, passport.js

I'm moving a project over to Vue.js and I can't get any of my middleware to check if users are logged in or to check user ownership of things to work. After searching endlessly, I believe that the problem is that the headers I send from my client to server don't contain the passport serialized user or something? How can I make this work?

Here is my login route on the back-end:

```
      router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
      res.send("Error");
    } else if(req.body.username.length > 40 || req.body.password.length > 40){
      res.send("Error");
    } else if (req.body.username) {
      req.body.username = req.body.username.toLowerCase();
      next();
    }
  }, passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }), function(req, res){
        User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user){
          if(err){
            res.send("User not found");
          } else {
            res.send(user.toJSON());
          }
        })
  });
```

Here is my login page on the client side:

```
          async login () {
          const response = await AuthenticationService.login({
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password,
            })
            if(response.data == "Error"){
                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'login'
                })
            } else {
            this.$store.dispatch('setUser', response.data._id);
            this.$router.push({
                name: 'home'
            })
            }
        }
```

Here is the axios call that AuthenticationService.login is referencing:

```
    login(credentials){
    return Api().post('login', credentials);
},
```

Api comes from:

```
import axios from 'axios';

 export default function(){
   return axios.create({
      baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/`
   });
  }
```

So how do I make the front-end send the right headers to the back-end after a user is authenticated? As you can see, I store the user id in a vuex state, but I don't think that would be safe to use to confirm ownership and whether or not users are logged in, right? Or would it? I could easily just send that over in the requests, is that right? I feel like that's not safe enough, but Idk what I'm talking about.

EDIT: Here is the passport setup in app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.session({ //5a6ba876578447262893ac69
    secret: "sessionSecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }));
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Comment: For sessions to work in passport/express, you need to define `[de]serializeUser` on the `passport` instance . Can you show *all* of the express/passport middleware you are using?

Comment: As for storing the user id in vuex state, that's totally fine as long as you use that for UI purposes (and not authoritative). You should store the users session token in cookies which are HttpOnly and use those to authenticate/authorize the user on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What happens on the server side when you attempt to access `POST /login`?

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I included the passport and express middleware in an edit above, however I think my issue is solely based on your second comment. How to I get the token? How do I save it? And how do I use it in other requests?

Comment: When I attempt to access POST/login t works exactly as it should

Comment: So, what's the problem? :) I'm assuming there's another route that is protected that you attempt to access that is not working, but you haven't included that in your question.

Comment: As for 'getting' the token - This is handled for you by the `express.session()` and `passport.session()` middlewares - they set a cookie in the response, which leaves the only potential issue being the code in your `User` module (which you have omitted). Could you include that?

Comment: You're exactly right. I have a middleware.isLoggedIn function, for example that checks "req.isAuthenticated()" before allowing access to other routes. So how do I get, store, and use the token from login to access those routes?

Comment: Not an issue with the User model. This application worked fine before moving it to Vue, I'm 99.9% certain that the issue is that my client requests don't include that token.

Comment: Hmm. The issue is definitely not with Vue. Vue does not manage HTTP requests nor would it modify the behaviour of the cookies. It might be with Axios. Are your front end and back end located on different domains? For example, the front end is hosted on localhost:3000 and the backend localhost:4000.

Comment: frontend is on localhost 8080 and localhost 8081

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is because your frontend and backend are on different domains.

Cookies, which `passport.session()`/`express.session()` use to maintain a user session, are scoped to a specific domain.

When you call `axios.get()` on the protected resource, axios will not send or receive cookies because `localhost:8080` is a different domain to `localhost:8081`.

Try `axios.get('/path/to/your/resource', { withCredentials: true })` and `axios.post('/login', { username, password }, { withCredentials: true })`

This would have been present even without Vue so long as you're using AJAX to make these calls.

Comment: I think this is probably it, thank you, Dan! But now I'm getting a cors error, do you know how to get around it?

Comment: Failed to load http://localhost:8081/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: You'll need to set the CORS headers. https://github.com/expressjs/cors. You should them to `localhost:8080` for now.

Comment: I already have app.use(cors()) in my app.js on the backend. Do I need to add that somewhere in the frontend too? If so, where exactly at?

Comment: No, it's a backend thing. As your error message mentions, you need to enable pre-flight requests, which is documented [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

Comment: Using that link I "enabled preflight across the board" with app.options('*', cors());, but I still get the same error

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much for all your help, Dan!

Answer (score 3):

requests.js

```js
let axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000/',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
  }
}
```

server.js

```js
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}))
```

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}))

Comment: thanks! i was missing the `credentials: true` in server